# How to know if a process handle is ready

Tags: c++, windows, process, handle

I open a process with `OpenProcess` in c++ but I can't use it right after I get it because I get an "Invalid handle error".  I know that the right handle because it gives me the right PID when I execute `GetProcessId` on this handle.
This is how I open the process.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dbghelp.h>
#pragma (lib, "dbghelp.lib");

bool EnablePrivilege(LPCTSTR lpszPrivilegeName, BOOL bEnable) 
{ 
    HANDLE hToken; 
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES    tp; 
    LUID luid; 
    bool ret; 

    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_READ, &hToken)) 
        return FALSE; 

    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, lpszPrivilegeName, &luid)) 
        return FALSE; 

    tp.PrivilegeCount           = 1; 
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid       = luid; 
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = bEnable ? SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED : 0; 

    ret = AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(tp), NULL, NULL); 
    CloseHandle(hToken); 

    return ret; 
}

void main()
{
    EnablePrivilege(SE_DEBUG_NAME, TRUE);

    STARTUPINFOA startInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
    ZeroMemory( &startInfo, sizeof(startInfo) );
    startInfo.cb = sizeof(startInfo);
    ZeroMemory( &processInfo, sizeof(processInfo) );
    DWORD creationFlags = DEBUG_PROCESS | DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS | PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION;
    const char* comLine = "Some process path and name";

//     Start the child process. 
    if( CreateProcessA( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
       (LPSTR)comLine, //argv[1],        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        creationFlags,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &startInfo,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &processInfo )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
     == false ) 
    {
        printf("FAIL!");
return;
    }

    SetLastError(0);
    bool ok = SymInitialize(processInfo.hProcess, NULL, true);
    int err = GetLastError();

}
```

For some reason the last erro value is garbage.
Is there a way to check if the process handle is ready for use?

Comment: what specifically would you like to see?

Comment: How you call `OpenProcess`, what do you do with the handle.

Comment: PROCESS_VM_READ and PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION are not valid process creation flags.

Comment: Ok, I removed them but it didn't help.

Comment: Re "For some reason the last erro value is garbage" -- the system sets last-error on error; it does not guarantee to not set last-error on not-an-error.  This can result in no error => last error is 'garbage'.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of the function in questions:

```
Return value

If the function succeeds, the return value is an open handle to the specified process.
```

This means that if the function succeeds you already get a usable handle i.e. you either get it or not, there is not middle ground where "you have to wait" for it to be usable. In your particular case chances are that your handle is invalid i.e the function has failed. Are you checking the return value for NULL? Have you used [GetLastError()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to see what's happening?

Comment: CreateProcess returns true, but also Last error = 2 (FILE NOT FOUND)

Comment: Try printing last error BEFORE and AFTER and see if it changes. Because GetLastError might be returning value from another failed function?

Comment: Also in your code you don't use OpenProcess but rather OpenProcessHandle - is this the function that is failing?

Comment: No, it originates from CreateProcess. AdjustPriviliegesToken gives last error 1300 (NOT ALL ASSIGNED) but i don't know if it's related.

Comment: I'm guessing that the invalid handle error is coming from SymInitialize, and indicates that the specified process is not in an appropriate state.  If fixing the creation flags doesn't help, I suggest you ask another question about how to properly use SymInitialize.

Comment: re "CreateProcess returns true, but also Last error = 2 (FILE NOT FOUND)".    The documentation says nothing about the validity of 'last error' if CreateProcess succeeds.   Quite possibly there was a file-not-found somewhere in the lengthy process-creation sequence.  It don't mean a thing if CreateProcess succeeded.